# Footer flexbox function not wokring

Tags: html, css, footer

I just started doing Front-End Web Development a few months ago and am still getting used to how all the properties work.

For some reason, my footer does not show the icons inline but leaves them vertical along with the text-decoration

Here is my website: jarrelthomas.com

and the code

HTML

```
<footer class="footer">
    <a href="mailto:jarrel.thomas@gmail.com" class="footer-link">Email</a>
    <ul class="social-list">
        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://www.instagram.com/jct_dev/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jarrel-thomas-2419646a/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>

        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://github.com/JarrelThomas"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>

        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://twitter.com/JCT_Dev"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
    background: #111;
    color: var(--clr-accent);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2.5em 0;
    font-size: var(--fs-h3);
}

.footer a { 
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer__link {
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}

.footer__link:hover,
.social-list__link:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}

.footer__link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.social-list ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-list__item {
    margin: 0 .5em;
}

.social-list__link {
    padding: .5em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `.social-list ul` you are specifying the `ul` inside `.social-list`, which specifies nothing in your case. You can do either `ul.social-list` or simply `.social-list`. If that wasn't a simple hiccup, then here's a the documentation for [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector containing flex code is incorrect. It should be `ul.social-list` not `.social-list ul`. Because you want to select a `ul` with a class of social-list, not a `ul` which is a child of something with a class of social-list.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect, like other guys has already mentioned. You should use:

```
ul.social-list
```

BTW, it's better to put class:hover definition under the class definition.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0czyso83/)

```css
.footer {
    background: lightcyan;
    color: var(--clr-accent);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2.5em 0;
    font-size: var(--fs-h3);
}

.footer a { 
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.footer__link {
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
}
ul.social-list {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2em 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.social-list__item {
    margin: 0 .5em;
}

.social-list__link {
    padding: .5em;
} 



.footer__link:hover,
.social-list__link:hover {
    opacity: .7;
}

.footer__link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="footer">
    <a href="mailto:jarrel.thomas@gmail.com" class="footer-link">Email</a>
    <ul class="social-list">
        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://www.instagram.com/jct_dev/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jarrel-thomas-2419646a/"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>

        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://github.com/JarrelThomas"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></li>

        <li class="social-list__item"><a class="social-list__link" 
            href="https://twitter.com/JCT_Dev"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```